# How to assign data to variable in ajax success call in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Hi I am developing Angularjs application. In ajax call i am getting data and i want to assign that data to variable but i am getting data as[object object].
Below is the data i am getting

```
{"data":{"ID":64,"OTP":2112},"status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/CheckUSer","data":{"FirstName":"dfd","LastName":"fdf","Gender":"Male","DateOfBirth":"2017-04-04","Nationality":"India","Mobile_CountryCod":"376","MobileNumber":"444","EmailId":"sdsdffffff","IsMobileVerified":false,"IsEmailVerified":false,"Home_Location":"q","Home_City":"q","Home_Neighbourhood":"q","Home_HouseNumber":"q","Home_MainStreet":"q","Home_SubStreet":"q","Work_Location":"q","Work_City":"q","Work_Neighbourhood":"q","Work_HouseNumber":"q","Work_MainStreet":"q","Work_SubStreet":"q","RequestedPlatform":"Web","RequestedLanguage":"English"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

Below is my code,

```
$http.post('http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/CheckUSer', RegistrationData).then(function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                var customerid = response.data.ID;
                var OTP = response.data.OTP;
                $state.go('Registration.OTPVerification', response);
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add HTML code

Comment: What do you mean by `but i am getting data as[object object]` ? What is not working actually ?

Comment: you should try passing response.data

Comment: Thank you.When i alert i am getting      alert(response); i am getting [object object]

Comment: If you are getting [Object object] in the alert then that is fine. Alerts don't show you the data inside an object.

Comment: use the console instead (console.log(response))

Comment: I am getting data if i put alert(response).

Comment: I want to assign data to variable. I do not have errors.

Comment: you can't show an object in alerts. need to convert it to string `alert(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: I fixed myself as below.  var pageList = response.data;
                var customerid = pageList.ID;
                var OTP = pageList.OTP;
                alert(OTP);
                alert(customerid);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is in a controller

*script.js*

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $http.post('http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/CheckUSer', RegistrationData).then(function (response) {

        $scope.customerid = response.data.ID;
        $scope.OTP = response.data.OTP;
    }


}]);
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController">

customerid = {{customerid}}, OTP = {{OTP}}

</body>
</html>
```